# Value returned by grecaptcha.render rejected as invalid

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I'm trying to put a Google "I'm not a robot" captcha on my page using explicit rendering and AJAX.

Here's my recaptcha onload callback:

```
function recaptchaLoaded() {
   elem.dataset.ffRecaptchaId = grecaptcha.render(elem, {
        'sitekey' : 'my key'
    });
}
```

I see the element on the page, so that call claerly succeeds.

Later on, I do this:

```
recaptcha_response = grecaptcha.getResponse(recaptcha_element.data('ff-recaptcha-id'));
```

This yield the error:

> Uncaught Error: Invalid ReCAPTCHA client id: 0

I have checked with a debugger, and 0 is the value returned by render()

What's the correct value to use here?

**(Solution)**

The problem was that I was accidentally importing the Recaptcha script twice, thus `grecaptcha` was being re-initialized after rendering the element on the page. Then the second grecaptcha obviously didn't know about the first element.